# Changing trains on DB saver fare in Warsaw Centralna instead of Zachodnia

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, poland, warsaw

I'm eyeing a saver fare ticket of Deutsche Bahn from Berlin to Krakow via Warsaw and intended to make a stopover in Warsaw of either one night or a few hours during the day (it doesn't really matter here).

The problem with that ticket is that it makes me change trains in Warszawa Zachodnia station (which is some 2-3 kms out of the centre) while to explore the city I would like to get off (and on again) in Warszawa Centralna station. Both trains do stop at the latter station, I guess the itinerary as such is because the overall time on trains is shorter. I have tried entering Warszawa Centralna in the "via" field of DB travel planner, and while it does display a solution on the same trains, the saver fare is no longer available. It also seems to me that on those trains no short-distance intracity tickets between Centralna and Zachodnia are sold.

So my question is, assuming I have the ticket with a change of trains in Zachodnia, can I stay on the train for one stop longer and get of in Centralna and again board the same train in Centralna? My main criterium is avoiding a fine and I'm willing to play the stupid tourist if need be, however I would like to avoid a loss of time either in formalities or having to take a regional train or other transport from Zachodnia to (and back from) the center.
Alternatively is there a way that I have overlooked to book the through-ticket on the saver fare via Warsaw Centralna instead of Zachodnia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the way from Berlin to Warszawa, you can safely simply miss Warszawa Zachodnia and in the very unlikely event there will be ticket control between Zachodnia and Centralna you can act surprised and worried that Zachodnia already passed, and I don't think anyone is going to give you a fine. I don't guarantee it, but I'd do it this way without worrying to much. The travel time between Zachodnia and Centralna is just 4 minutes, and everyone on the train is getting up and taking their luggage and piling up in the corridor to get off at Centralna, and even if a ticket inspector would like to check tickets between these stations, it would be very difficult given the short time and crowded space and everyone packing up and generally a big mess.

The other way (Centralna - Zachodnia) the above doesn't apply any more, but you can either try to buy a ticket Warszawa Centralna - Warszawa Zachodnia at the counter in Centralna (should be possible, but I am not sure now), or if that fails just take a bus or another local train (for which you can surely buy tickets locally), or even if its not possible to buy a ticket between these stations for that train, just buy any random local ticket between these stations at the counter and still board that train, so at least you have something if the inspector starts to check tickets there, and even if its the wrong ticket, you can just say you didn't know, and most likely he'll let you go, or in the worst case sell another ticket with some ~10 PLN (less then 3 EUR) surcharge for selling a ticket on the train. Polish ticket inspectors are likely to not give you a full fine, but allow you to buy the right ticket from him with a small ~10 PLN surcharge if you at least have some kind of ticket which one might think might be valid for this train (even if strictly it isn't), or if you are past the station you should get off and you claim you missed the station. They will only give you a full fine if you don't have any ticket at all. You will have to be very unlucky to meet an inspector which would give you a full expensive fine in that situation, most will just sell you the missing ticket (in the very unlikely event that you meet them between Zachodnia and Centralna at all).

**Note regarding EIP trains:**

However in case your train Warszawa-Kraków is an EIP train, then I would take a different train on the way from Warszawa Centralna to Warszawa Zachodnia, because the rules regarding travelling without a ticket on EIP trains are vastly different then on "normal" (not-EIP) polish trains. First of all it is not allowed to buy the ticket from the train staff, and the fines are vastly higher (650 PLN fee on EIP vs the standard 10 PLN surcharge on any other train in case of the same infraction of boarding the train without the right ticket). I have never traveled on an EIP train yet, so I would be cautious applying any of my previous advice on an EIP train, as the ticket inspectors might be much more strict there.

Comment: Thanks, +1! So to board the second train in Centralna I will need some type of ticket to access the platform and or the train? (I.e. it is different from German train stations where you can walk up to any train freely). I will have a valid ticket for that train from Warsaw Zachodnia to Krakow, my only concern is these 5 minutes between Centralna and Zachodnia.

Comment: @mts no, the platforms are freely accessible, you don't need a ticket to access it. The ticket is just some kind of insurance against a fine in the unlikely event the inspector comes in these 4 minutes (because you can't  claim you missed your station).

Comment: @mts the only trains in Poland where your ticket is checked on the platform before being allowed to board the train are sleeper/couchettes.

Comment: Thanks again and already accepted. You might also know the answer to my other question here: [Extra luggage ticket on Intercity.pl necessary?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76173/32134)

Comment: @mts I just saw in the other question that you are taking EIP train from Warsaw. In that case, I would take a different train from Warszawa Centralna to Warszawa Zachodnia, because the rules regarding travelling without a ticket on EIP trains are vastly different then on "normal" (not-EIP) polish trains. First of all it is not allowed to buy the ticket from the train staff, and the fines are vastly higher. I have never traveled on an EIP train yet, so I would be cautious applying the above advice to an EIP train, as the ticket inspectors might be much more strict there.

Comment: thanks for checking back - I did end up getting two different tickets, both to and from Warszawa Centralna, as the ticket I planned to get turned out more expensive than I thought while the other way round I'm saving even taking the EIP. So my main concern is now the luggage as asked in the other Q, if you know anything about it your answer will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: After having done this part of my trip (while I did have valid tickets for the whole journey), there were no controls on the Warsaw Zachodnia to Centralna part on both trains and if I were to be in the situation again, I might very well consider dodging the fare for those few kms.