# Extra luggage ticket on Intercity.pl necessary?

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, luggage, poland

I was about to buy a ticket on [intercity.pl](http://www.intercity.pl/en/) and noticed that there is an option to select an "extra luggage" ticket for a few zloty.

- When do I need this ticket?

or:

- How much luggage can I carry on a regular ticket without the extra luggage option?

I will be traveling with a medium sized suitcase and a medium/large 55l backpack plus a small bag at most.

Bonus questions:

- Is this extra luggage ticket enforced if needed and one fails to purchase?
- Can one easily purchase the extra luggage ticket later on, or even on the train, without an extra fee? In my scenario I would buy an online ticket now, a few weeks before travel.

[image]

From what I noted the luggage option is available for all of the faster train types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [their transport information](http://www.intercity.pl/en/site/for-passengers/services/transport-of-bicycles,-items-and-pets/przewoz-rzeczy-en/):

> You may take as your hand luggage at no additional charge objects
> which are easy to move – those which may be freely placed above and
> under the space occupied by you in train.
>
> **When I have to pay for my luggage?**
>
> - If you transport objects which are
>   easy to move but cannot be freely placed above and under the space
>   occupied by you on train. In that event an extra fee of PLN 5.10 is
>   charged for each oversize item;
> - When transporting one unfolded and
>   unpackaged bicycle (details and instructions on the transport of
>   bicycles can be found in our "Guide for bicycle owners").

If you don't pay beforehand:

> In the event that a passenger has not paid a fare at a ticket window
> for the transport of an item, the intention that this be transported
> should be reported to the conductor prior to the journey beginning,
> i.e. before entering or immediately after entering the train. A ticket
> for the transport of an item on an EIP train may be purchased at a
> ticket window only.
>
> Please be reminded that an additional charge of PLN 10 is made for the
> issue of a ticket from a conductor on a train.

If you fail to do that, then fines are incurred:

> In the event that a passenger has not forewarned the conductor of the
> intention that an item be transported, then – besides the charge for
> item transport of PLN 5.10 – an additional charge is also made, set on
> the basis of the directive of the Ministry of Infrastructure of 20
> January 2005. The charge at this point amounts to PLN 52, and in the
> event that settlement of the amount due is refused a summons is issued
> – a protocol with an additional charge of PLN 260. If the passenger
> pays the charge within seven days of the date of issue of the summons,
> the charge amounts to PLN 65.

To be honest, I can't imagine anyone ever pays for this unless there's a separate luggage car which I don't think there is.

Comment: +1 but I'd really need to know how large the overhead bins are which is what I guess they intend with " be freely placed above and under the space occupied by you on train."

Comment: Adding to my last comment, [pictures on seat61.com](http://seat61.com/Poland.htm#Krakow) suggest that there are no overhead bins at all.

Comment: @mts http://www.vagonweb.cz/fotogalerie/PL/PKP_ED250.php shows there are overhead bins on the EIP trains and they look to be quite big. Are you going to be on EIP though?

Comment: Looks like I got an EIP. I didn't buy the extra luggage ticket as in case it seems I could buy it at the station before boarding in case. The website also has a mean 2min countdown when booking that is not intended for someone navigating their website for the first time, bar a slow internet connection.

Comment: Recently when I was travelling on a train in Poland, I was asked by the ticket inspector to buy a ticket for my luggage (he didn't issue a fine, just sold me the ticket with a 10 PLN surcharge). This happened first time in my life, but the luggage was so large I was not able to put it in the compartment at all, and it was blocking the alley. So it appears that the rule is now enforced, but only if the luggage doesn't fit in storage spaces assigned for luggage and needs to occupy passenger walking/sitting space.

Comment: Also remember that in case of EIP trains, buying a ticket from the ticket inspector is not possible, so better buy the ticket beforehand if you think it might not fit in provided luggage space.

Comment: @OmegaTerus I notice your comments here only now, you might want to make them an answer? Regarding your last comment, while buying the train ticket from the inspector is not possible, is there a chance that buying the extra luggage one is possible?

Comment: So I took my research trip and with regular luggage there was no need, there are the regular luggage compartments as you find them in trains where my suitcase fit and backpack would easily fit overhead. I assume the fee is mostly for bikes and when your luggage is really huge, but I'm still not sure what you do with a suitcase when the luggage rack is full?