# How does excess luggage work on Polish trains?

Tags: trains, luggage, poland

I booked a seat on the Warsaw-Torun train for tomorrow. The FAQ on the PKP Intercity website says that if you're carrying baggage that won't fit overhead or under the seat, that you need to pay an excess luggage fee. Since I've got a larger backpack, and the fee was only 5.10 PLN, I paid the fee.

So now my ticket clearly says that I have paid for "stuff" (literally *rzeczy*), and I'm curious how this works. From what I've read, luggage storage is limited to overhead and under-seat storage. You pay this fee when you think that this storage option isn't sufficient, but what does it actually give you?

Comment: Related or dupe, you decide: [Extra luggage ticket on Intercity.pl necessary?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76173/32134)

Comment: @mts I think it's just related. I actually bought the extra luggage rider and now I'm wondering how it wirks., whereas that question is asking if it's necessary to buy it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you could have done without the fee, I did store a large backpack overhead + a large suitcase in the suitcase thing at the beginning of the train car. About your Q I cant say, I have to admit it is not that clear what your actual question is? I mean you purchased the right to carry one very large item, no?!

Comment: Thats what I don't even understand. I effectively agreed that I have luggage that won't fit in the available storage locations, so I bought the right to bring my bigger luggage and store it... somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the overhead racks, which were indeed ample enough to fit my 70L pack, there were two standalone luggage racks in the second class car for storing oversized luggage. At no time did the conductor check my ticket and match me with the bag in the oversized storage, thouh.

For completeness sake I will also point out that there were six berths for bicycles on the entire train. These were also purchased as an additional fee on the ticket, and I did notice that this was actually checked by the conductor.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you have to pay this extra fee in case when your luggage is something non-standard (not a backpack nor a suitcase), large or heavy enough that you have to put it on the ground or in the corridor (hence, partially blocking way) or taking seats you didn't pay for. Otherwise, as you noticed, if everything fits luggage compartments or shelves and no other co-passanger is complaining that there is no room left for his luggage, then you're OK and no one would bother.

Comment: no, I'm saying about the case when luggage is too large to fit overhead shelves and lays on the seat because of that, If you have a small backpack, and seat next to you is empty, I'm sure no one would bother charging you with extra fee (because your small backpack can be easily moved around when owner of the seat asks for it), please use common sense

Comment: again, use common sense; if you have a large backpack or a large suitcase but you can put it in the overhead rack -> you don't have to pay;
if you have a bicycle with you -> you have to pay extra;
if you have a large piece of luggage which you're unable to store where it belongs (or somewhere, where it could disturb anyone or block the corridor) -> you have to pay extra